# Using command echo in a .sh file doesn't works in TWRP recovery. How to do to display message using script .sh in TWRP

Tags: android, sh, recovery

I'm trying to understand why using echo command in sh file doesn't work.
I've made a flashable zip with 7-zip, it contains a shell script.
The updater-script is

```
ui_print("");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");
run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/data");
package_extract_dir("test", "/tmp");
set_perm(0, 0, 0777, "/tmp/test.sh");
run_program("/tmp/test.sh");
delete_recursive("/tmp");
unmount("/system");
unmount("/data");
```

and my test.sh is like this :

```
    #!/sbin/sh

   rm -rf /system/app/YouTube
   echo "Delete Youtube"
```

test.sh deletes Youtube folder but echo command doesn't work.

I use TWRP 3.2.3.0 recovery.

I know command works echo because i see it in recovery.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWRP recovery redirects echo to log file;
stdout and stderror are redirected to the log.

So if we want to display message on screen , we have to make a function to redirect it to the right file descriptor.
I've found this code from supersu from chainfire that does exactly what i was looking for

```
#!/sbin/sh

OUTFD=1
readlink /proc/$$/fd/$OUTFD 2>/dev/null | grep /tmp >/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
  # rerouted to log file, we don't want our ui_print commands going there
  OUTFD=0

  # we are probably running in embedded mode, see if we can find the right fd
  # we know the fd is a pipe and that the parent updater may have been started as
  # 'update-binary 3 fd zipfile'
  for FD in `ls /proc/$$/fd`; do
    readlink /proc/$$/fd/$FD 2>/dev/null | grep pipe >/dev/null
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
      ps | grep " 3 $FD " | grep -v grep >/dev/null
      if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
        OUTFD=$FD
        break
      fi
    fi
  done
fi

ui_print() {
  echo -n -e "ui_print $1\n" >> /proc/self/fd/$OUTFD
  echo -n -e "ui_print\n" >> /proc/self/fd/$OUTFD
}
```

To display message just use ui_print "message..."

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the correct shebang

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Bash has a built-in echo command. You can leverage that if the standard echo binary isn't functional

Comment: Well instead of downvoting, you probably need to understand that the /bin/bash has to be installed first.  As an alternative, try echo "Delete Youtube" > file 

Then check if file is created and that "cat file" gives you your string. If it does, then there's no problem with the echo command. It's just that you cannot see where it is printing as it is running in a separate shell.

Comment: i'm not downvoting your answer